# Making check_http (Nagios) check for a certain number of strings

Tags: string, centos, nagios

I've been trying for quite a while to figure out if there's a way to make the check_http plugin for Nagios scan for a certain number of instances of a string on a web page and notify me once it passes that number.

For example, if I'm outputting a log file to a web page and want Nagios to notify me if the text "error" comes up on the page more than, say, 3 times, how would I phrase the command? There might even be a different plugin altogether that allows me to bypass the webpage and look for those 3 instances of "error" directly in the log file. If anyone knows of such a plugin, that information would be appreciated, too.

If it matters, I'm running CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via a cunningly constructed regexp.  However, you then get the problem that you have to negate the response as check_http doesn't provide a 'not regexp' option (I feel it should, but it doesn't).

So, if you want to alert on >3 instances of 'error', use something like this:

```
negate "check_http www.myserver.co.nz -r '(error.*){4}'"
```

You might want to do a separate check to identify slow responses, though, and the returned information string might be a bit misleading.

If you can check the file directly (or via NRPE) then you could write a script to use egrep with a similar regexp.